# How to pass different arrays in table view on click of different rows of picker view?

Tags: swift3

I set a picker view and I want that when I will click on a row of picker view the table view cell label in next view controller will change according to the different rows of picker view.

I tried this by taking an `Int` variable and in the `didSelectRow` method of the picker view, I have done this:

```
i = Int(row)
```

Then in `tableview cellForRowAtIndexpath` method I have done this:

```
switch i {
case 0:
  cell.textlabel.text = "one"
case 1:
  cell.textlabel.text = "two"
```

... but it's not working.

Please suggest how I can do this.

Comment: Could you post a bit more code please? It's difficult to know what's missing from what you have posted here.

Comment: gangozo can you please tell me if i want that on click of different rows of picker view the textlabel of tableview cell change so what will i have to do for this.?

Comment: It's just not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you need to add `tableView.reloadData` to the `didSelectRow` method of the picker view?